# How do I import an eclipse workspace into intelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, workspace

I have recently moved from Eclipse / STS to intelliJ and want to export eclipse workspace into intelliJ. I have multiple workspaces with logically grouped projects that I have been working on. While looking for same on idea website or SO, i found multiple results for importing an eclipse project into idea but i am looking for a way where i could have my entire workspace impoorted ( may be as a project and module ?). Is there any way to achieve the same easily ?

Comment: Not sure if there is but make a back up first! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just open the eclipse workspace in IDEA: click **Import Project** on the **Welcome Screen**, or select **File | New | Project from Existing Sources** in the main menu. See this doc for more information:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html#migratingEclipseProject

IntelliJ IDEA will convert your workspace to project and your projects to modules inside this project.

Comment: This is way to do it.  It is "brand new", so you'll have to transfer environment variable(s) and vm arguments.  When I have alot of settings, one "trick" I use is to create an environment variable named "peanut" and value of "butter", then I search "workspace.xml" for peanut....and then I can add more environment variables by manipulating the xml instead of adding through the GUI.

Comment: PS, when you find the folder for "from existing sources", find the root pom.xml file.

Comment: @granadaCoder  I selected the workspace folder from import project option. It popped up a new window asking if its eclipse, maven or few others project. After selecting eclipse, I see a new project with all eclipse projects exported as modules, but all the new modules contain a .classpath and .project with eclipse icon. Is it supposed to be this way ?

Comment: Fount out that the new path I selected for intelliJ option of "keep projects and modules files in" just contain one .idea directory and multiple .iml files for each project. Selecting the option of show in explore still options my eclipse directory, I am not looking to keep these files in sync.

Comment: No, you don't pick your workspace folder as your "start folder" for the import.  You pick the folder with your top-most pom.xml.  If you have a monolith, then you probably only have one pom.xml :(           If you have several maven modules, pick your pom.xml that has the links to the other maven modules.    Offtopic: If you're building monoliths, please consider something else : https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Comment: @granadaCoder Few of my workspaces have only Java projects that I used while learning core concepts. Is it possible to migrate them too, without having any link between eclipe and idea projects ?